# Android: Repeating List View

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a list view to display images vertically. I was wondring if there is a way to repeat images in the list view when user has scrolled to the end of the list. e.g. if list has 3 images, after scrolling down to the 3rd and last image, the same images should repeat in 1,2,3 order again. So kind off giving a circular repeat effect to the viewer. Is there another option besides list view?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that effect with a custom Adapter.

CommonsWare has made one that you can re-use if you wish: [cwac-endless](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

If your looking to create it yourself you can of course do that too. Inside your adapter what you need to do is return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from the `getCount()` method.

And then inside your `getView()` use modulus to "convert" a larger number to down to one within the range for how many items you actually have. i.e. if you have an array of image id's you could do something like this inside your getView():

```
mImgView.setImageResource(imgs[pos % 3]);
```

You could do the modulus inside of getItem() instead of getView() actually, that is probably a better idea.

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. I had a custom adapter only thing that I missing was mImgView.setImageResource(imgs[pos % 3]);